# Calculation from Unlimited Multidimensional Array Levels

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

can anyone intelligent here help me regarding making function for calculating unlimited levels of childs in array?

below if you see i have 3 levels in array such as child in child in child of parent "A". so far i'm using php `for-loop` to go through each level of array and doing some calculation that should be understandable from below function `example_TreeCalc`. basically i'm going in all levels of array and summing `revPoints` and `revPoints_calculated` in two different variables. and later i am subtracting them.

PS: my friend told me to solve this by DFS. i checked that algorithm but couldn't find a way to do those calculations via DFS. if someone willing to create any example of doing below calculation via given array using DFS. I will highly appreciate that as well.

Thank you!

```
$example_Tree = array(
    'name'      => 'A',
    'revPoints' => '300.00',
    'revPoints_calculated' => '120.00',
    'child'=>  array(
        array(
            'name' => 'B',
            'revPoints' => '250.00',
            'revPoints_calculated' => '30.00',
            'child' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'C',
                    'revPoints' => '0.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '0.00',
                    'child' => array()

                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'D',
                    'revPoints' => '250.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '10.00',
                    'child' => array()

                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'E',
                    'revPoints' => '1150.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '92.00',
                    'child' => array()
                ),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'C',
            'revPoints' => '1200.00',
            'revPoints_calculated' => '541.00',
            'child' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'D',
                    'revPoints' => '2000.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '160.00',
                    'child' => array()

                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'E',
                    'revPoints' => '3500.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '420.00',
                    'child' => array()

                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'F',
                    'revPoints' => '850.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '34.00',   
                    'child' => array()

                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'G',
                    'revPoints' => '150.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '0.00',
                    'child' => array()
                ),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'D',
            'revPoints' => '800.00',
            'revPoints_calculated' => '100.00',
            'child' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'E',
                    'revPoints' => '300.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '12.00',
                    'child' => array()

                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'F',
                    'revPoints' => '300.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '12.00',
                    'child' => array()

                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'G',
                    'revPoints' => '150.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '0.00',
                    'child' => array()
                ),
            )

        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'E',
            'revPoints' => '100.00',
            'revPoints_calculated' => '0.00',
            'child' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'F',
                    'revPoints' => '800.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '32.00',
                    'child' => array()
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'G',
                    'revPoints' => '350.00',
                    'revPoints_calculated' => '76.00',
                    'child' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'H',
                            'revPoints' => '800.00',
                            'revPoints_calculated' => '32.00',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'I',
                            'revPoints' => '100.00',
                            'revPoints_calculated' => '0.00',
                        ),
                    )
                ),
            )
        ),
    ),
);

dump($example_Tree);


function example_TreeCalc($tree) {
    $treeParent = $tree['name'];
    $revPercentTotal =  0;
    $revTotal =  0;
    $childTree_level_1 = $tree['child'];
    // dump('child Tree level 1=>', count($childTree_level_1));
    if (isset($childTree_level_1)) {
        for ($i=0; $i < count($childTree_level_1); $i++) { 

            $childTree_level_2 = $childTree_level_1[$i]['child'];
            // dump('child Tree level 2=>', count($childTree_level_2));
            if (isset($childTree_level_2)) {

                for ($j=0; $j < count($childTree_level_2); $j++) {

                    $childTree_level_3 = $childTree_level_2[$j]['child'];
                    // dump('child Tree level 3=>', count($childTree_level_3));
                    if (isset($childTree_level_3)) {

                        for ($k=0; $k < count($childTree_level_3); $k++) {
                            $revPercentTotal += $childTree_level_3[$k]['revPoints_calculated'];
                            $revTotal += $childTree_level_3[$k]['revPoints'];
                        }

                    }
                    $revPercentTotal += $childTree_level_2[$j]['revPoints_calculated'];
                    $revTotal += $childTree_level_2[$j]['revPoints'];                
                }

            }
            $revPercentTotal += $childTree_level_1[$i]['revPoints_calculated'];
            $revTotal += $childTree_level_1[$i]['revPoints'];
        }
    }

    echo "BEFORE revPercentTotal $revPercentTotal" . "<br/>";
    echo "BEFORE revTotal $revTotal" . "<br/>";

    // $revPercentTotal += $tree['revPoints_calculated'];
    // $revTotal += $tree['revPoints'];


    echo "revTotal $revTotal " . "<br/>";
    echo "revPercentTotal $revPercentTotal" . "<br/>";


    $commission = number_format($revTotal - $revPercentTotal,2);

    return array('Name'=> $treeParent, 'Commission'=> $commission); 
}

dump(exampleTreeCalc($example_Tree));
```

Comment: Can you describe calculation logic a bit, please? Do you want to simply sum up all `revPoints` and all `revPoints_calculated`, and then calculate difference?

Comment: hello bro, yup for now yes. 

but additionally, there were some calculation involved in sub child level. for example after 1 level, In any other level, i needed to take sum of `revPoints` of all individual arrays in child and return that sum to there belonging parent with some subtraction etc. For now i just hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

If no other logic than plain summation is involved you can use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
$revPercentTotal = 0;
$revTotal = 0;
array_walk_recursive($example_Tree, function ($value, $key) use (&$revPercentTotal, &$revTotal) {
    if ($key === 'revPoints_calculated') {
        $revPercentTotal += $value;
    } elseif ($key === 'revPoints') {
        $revTotal += $value;
    }
});

$commision = number_format($revTotal - $revPercentTotal, 2);
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18699550218be46c57e07e1efab04eb5d446bc5c).

Comment: hey bro thank you. i am testing your code. hold on please :)

Comment: this function looks nice but did you saw that it doesn't return same result! the output is wrong

Comment: @Danish, your function doesn't take in the account first level values: `'revPoints' => '300.00', 'revPoints_calculated' => '120.00'`. You did this on purpose?

Comment: yes bro initially, it was intended to be added but later it was decided not to. thus i had to remove & not include first level values which is the Parent of whole tree. Moreover, it is also because whole tree calculation is being done for the main first level parent of whole tree.

Comment: a work around for your solution could be that after `array_walk_recursive` you can subtract from first index's but i wonder is that a good solution?

yup i tired this workaround. its outputing correct, check this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01fa38a34c09060143a852d302fa3653cc5861de

Comment: @Danish, you can just paste `$example_Tree['child']` to the `array_walk_recursive` instead of `$example_Tree`.

Comment: well for now i would appreciate your solution by voting it. Thank you very much for the effort bro!